# jQuery body resize listener

Tags: jquery, resize, listener

I am looking for a listener to body resize.
I need something similiar to `$(window).resize()` but for the body.

Why do I need it for the body? I add content using ajax and it might change the body size (depends on user's resolution).

How can I make body resize listener / where can I find one?

**EDIT:**
except for the ajax, I got accordion.
each Item has different height and therefore can cause the body to resize...

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a cross-browser solution to this.  Why not just run the checks regardless of whether the body resized after the ajax request or not?

Comment: a) Store original body width/height, b) do AJAX, c) compare width/height to original.

Comment: well, this is not the only problem. I got accordion in my web, each item has different height, therefore each might cause or not the body to resize...

Comment: I don't think its a good idea. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I have dynamic div which holds my advertisement. the div is aligned to the right of my web, if there content is too big and there's content, my web is slightly more to the left (center automatically).

Comment: @Ron you should not have to listen for body resize to keep your page centered.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I dont need it in order to keep my page centered. I need it to keep my DYNAMIC div in the right place. if scrollbar suddenly appear it cause the website to move a little bit to the left, then I need to move the dynamic div a bit to the left...

Comment: @Ron OIC. Is the dynamic box colliding with other content when the scrollbar appears? Or is it just visually unpleasing?

Comment: @Fresheyeball not colliding but the margin between the dynamic box to the rest of the web becomes bigger ~significantly~.

Comment: @Ron and is it always or usually the accordion that is causing the jump?

Comment: @Fresheyeball whenever element's height changed and caused vertical scrollbar appear. but only the accordion changes the height so yeah...

Comment: @Ron are you using jquery-ui for the accordion?

Comment: @Fresheyeball no. my own code using slideup/slidedown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reliable way to listen for body resize, BUT you can listen for animation occurring in your accordion. There are two ways to do this, but one of them is cooler.

Somewhere in your accordion script you have a jQuery `.animate` statement. If you don't and are using a shortcut like `.show(200)` or `.fadeIn`, you will need to convert it to a `.animate` statement. All these commands are really just shortcuts for `.animate` anyway. If you are using `slideUp` and `slideDown`. You will have to save the height of your elements when the slider is initialized for use later (this is what jQuery is doing behind the scenes btw).

Next you will want to use the step property of .animate to listen for the presence of the scrollbar:

```
  $(accordionSlideToShow).animate({
        height : 200
        step : function(){
            //scrollbar checking and css control script here
        }
  }, 2000);
```

But if you want to be cooler, you can add custom events to your widget. This way future development can tie into these events as free functionality.

```
  $(accordionSlideToShow).trigger('ron-accordion-slideWillShow').animate({
        height : 200
        step : function(){
             $(accordionParentElement).trigger('ron-accordion-animationOccurring');
        }
  }, 2000, function(){
      $(this).trigger('ron-accordion-slideDidShow');
  });
```

Now you can tie into your widget's new event model and listen for animation and scrollbars like so:

```
  $(accordionInstance).on('ron-accordion-animationOccurring', function(){
       //test for scroll bars and add css if needed
  });
```

Comment: this is pretty smart, Although I use another solution which is much more simple. I have a callback function for the slideup/down which fixes the dynamic div position. much faster and easier way I guess. no idea why I didnt think about that before..

Comment: Well there is still one benefit. This method would catch the scroll bar the moment it appears, instead of only after animation is complete. But whatever works!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such `resize` event that triggers when the body element changes size - you can assign a `resize` event handler, but this will only trigger when the window resizes. There are a few ways to approximate an element resize event, but as Fresheyeball states it's probably better to try and approach the problem from a different angle. That being said you could:

1. Create a function that is frequently called via `setInterval` that would keep an eye on the `width`/`height` or the `scrollWitdth`/`scrollHeight` of the body, and fire a method if there is a change.
2. In browsers that support this feature you could look at using the `DOMAttrModified` event or possibly make use of a `MutationObserver`. But then again these are only supported by a small percentage of the user agents out there.

   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events
   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver